# Store information about supplier's products

Tags: windows, linux, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

I work for a small company. We regularly have discussions with our suppliers, in which they send us information and documents about their products. This information comes in various formats (text in e-mails, datasheets, pdfs, quotes, spreadsheets) and is difficult to centralize, organize and share with the team. I'm looking for a software solution that would :

- be able to handle around 50 to 100 products
- store various files for each product (pdfs, spreadsheets, etc.)
- track the source of the information (public website, discussion, conference, etc.)
- store additional notes (context of the discussion, confidentiality of the information, etc.)
- be cross-platform (at least Windows and Linux), ideally web-based

I've looked into Product Information Management solutions, but these tend to be geared towards e-commerce firms, while we are an engineering company. Our current method is a shared spreadsheet with basic file folders.

Answer (score 1):

The only product I get in mind is [Apache OFBiz](https://ofbiz.apache.org/). This product will offer you a lot of options, it is web based, but it's not so sample and need effort to be customized for your needs (it is not ready to use for your purpose).

Because it is Java based you can run it on (almost) any operating system.